# Verify stripe payment amount

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

For my shopping site I have a fairy simple stripe implementation on the frontend where user hits "pay through stripe" button fills in CC details in a popup and hits proceed. If all goes well I get a token as `$_POST['stripeToken']` which I process like below (for web payments)

```
try
{

  $stripe = new Stripe();
  $stripe = Stripe::make();

  $customer = $stripe->customers()->create([
   'email' => $_POST['email_id'],
   'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken']
  ]);

  $charge =  $stripe->charges()->create([
  'customer' => $customer['id'],
  'amount'   => $total_amount, // note this is calculated again on server to prevent fraud
  'currency' => 'sgd'
  ]);


}
catch (\Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\CardErrorException $e)
{
  return view('front.payment_error')->with('message', $e->getMessage());
}
```

Thing is we cannot rely on `$total_amount` coming from frontend form submission as user can easily spoof this amount and pay just $1 in stripe and get a token and spoof `$total_amount` to `1` thus getting products at whatever price he wants ,that's why I need to calculate his `$total_amount again on  the server (from his cart) and use that to process stripe on the server.If that amount doesn't match what the token stands for , stripe would automatically raise an exception and prevent fraud.

So far good.. but the problem comes when dealing with API , mobile app will process stripe using their own libs. on the client side they would just send the final (for recording in db) but obviously I cannot use it to charge since that is already done on the mobile.Since these days it's very easy to change app behaviour (by patching apks) or craft custom HTTP request (postman) , server check is a must in case of payments.

So my question is how can I verify from the token the actual amount user paid

ie. reverse convert `stripeToken => actual paid amount`

**Update:**
This is what I am looking in case of Stripe 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

Comment: Have you thought of making the mobile app also pay through the same API as the website?

Comment: yes I thought about this but then what's the point of using mobile SDKs if we  were to use server for processing the payment.I want to just verify payment details.